# Php base64 string to image

Tags: php, base64

I get base64 string from my android appliation using which the php script saves it to the directory everything works fine for png. except **i need the script to work for all image types**
At android side i have **httpservlet extended class** and using which i send a get request with a variable containing base64 string. **So all we have is a base64 string nothing else at server side** 
Can you help me with that??
This is my php code

```
<?php

 $imgstr = $_REQUEST['string'];


      // Decode the data
$data = base64_decode($imgstr);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);

$success = file_put_contents("img/abc". uniqid().".png", $data);
imagedestroy($im);
if ($success) {
    echo 'yes yes yes';
}
} else {
echo 'An error occurred.';
```

}
   ?>

Comment: Did you check to see if it's sending a $_file from the submission form?

Comment: There is no submission form i am sending through android using httprequest. just one variable string of bas64

Comment: How do you pass data, when it's not being passed through a type of form?  Is an applet that passes data to your PHP server still not a type of form?

Comment: At android side i have  httpservlet extended class and using which i send a get request with a variable containing base64 string. So all we have is a base64 string nothing else at server side

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: Yes i just calculated the mime type befor encoding to base64 and sent that as a variable too

Comment: then post the solution, or mark solved ;) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so what i did was that i  just calculated the mime type before encoding to base64 and sent that as a variable too

This is how i did it

```
 public static String getMimeType(String url) {
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}   

   mimetype = getMimeType(picturePath);
   String temp[] = mimetype.split("/");
   as.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mime", temp[1]));
```

After this as was sent to server along with image.

Comment: So you researched it on your own.  I thought it would be sent to the server as a $_FILE, but I guess not.